# Python telebot конкретный юзер

Tags: python, telebot, pymongo

Суть проблеми: Пользователь ведет беседу з ботом. Нужно записать в базу данных что говорит конкретный юзер. Например, есть много юзеров. Бот должен знать, что юзер А имеет имя Вася, юзер Б имеет имя Петя.

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, commands=["start"])
def send_welcome(message):
    if db.collection.find_one({"_id": message.chat.id}) is None:
        db.collection.insert({"_id": message.chat.id})
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hi, mate. Do you want to play the game?", reply_markup=config.markup)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, commands=["register"])
def register_name(message):
    name = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "What's your nickname?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(name, register_experience)

def register_experience(message):
    try:
        db.collection.find({"_id"})#Проверям что это юзер А, например.
        db.user.update({"name": message.text})#Запысиваем, что юзер А имеет имя .. 
        experience = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "What's your experience?")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(experience, register_age)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ooops {0}".format(e))
```

Буду очень благодарен за любою совет. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте:

```
def register_experience(message):
with open('names.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(str(message.chat.id) + ' is ' + message.text + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Целесообразнее иметь для этого базу данных. Делаем таблицу с колонами "Name" и "chaid". Объяснять что они хранят думаю не нужно. Для этого используем например библиотеку sqlite3.

Comment: "Объяснять что они хранят думаю не нужно" - нужно. Мне вот не понятно, что за зверь такой - "chaid". Если это сокращение от chat + id - то это неудачное сокращение, никогда не видел чтобы так что-то сокращали.

Comment: Хотя сама по себе идея хранить данные в базе - здравая.

Comment: Спасибо, я новичек на stackoverflow. Прислушаюсь к вашему комментарию, спасибо